# App icon on Play Store is blurry and distorted

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I just uploaded my app to the Google Play Store, not in production but in Open Tesing.
In the browser version of Google Play everything is fine.

The problem is, that on the Play Store app on my phone the icon of my app has a very bad resolution and weird spots in it. It's the same thing with the pictures of my app on the Play Store.

[Image of the blurry icon on Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4wUG.jpg)

[Better image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Vdt.jpg)

[Image of the app icon on the Play Store Browser version (Everything fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztERT.png)

The link opens the Play Store browser version where it's working: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sleept

I already tried using other devices, but it didn't work.

Comment: The icon on mobile is just more compressed. There is nothing you can do.

Comment: @user1467216 So there is absolutely no way I can improve the quality? Maybe changing the file size?